# Solr query to compare two dates in same document

Tags: solr

I have some solr documents where there are two dates viz publishDate and documentCreateDate.

I want to compare both dates with each other.

So how to query solr for that?

Comment: What's the goal of comparing the two dates? Sorting? Filtering?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ms function query](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/function-queries.html#ms-function) for that. The result will be the number of milliseconds between the two dates.

> `ms` Returns milliseconds of difference between its arguments.
>   Dates are relative to the Unix or POSIX time epoch, midnight, January
>   1, 1970 UTC.
>
> Arguments may be the name of a DatePointField, TrieDateField, or date
>   math based on a constant date or NOW.
>
> `ms()`: Equivalent to `ms(NOW)`, number of milliseconds since the epoch.
>
> `ms(a)`: Returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch that the
>   argument represents.
>
> `ms(a,b)`: Returns the number of milliseconds that
>   `b` occurs before `a` (that is, `a - b`)
>
> **Syntax Examples**
>
> `ms(NOW/DAY)`
>
> `ms(NOW,mydatefield)`
>
> `ms(mydatefield, 2000-01-01T00:00:00Z)`
>
> `ms(datefield1, datefield2)`
>
> `ms(2000-01-01T00:00:00Z)`
>
> `ms(mydatefield)`

The `ms(datefield1, datefield2)` form is in particular relevant for what you want to achieve.